# How to install Tableau Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, tableau

Is it possible to install Tableau Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04?

I tried to find out ways. One of the way - *Installing a windows VM on my ubuntu machine and installing Tableau there.*

Is there any other **better** way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry no. It is native to Windows.

Comment: https://www.tableau.com/products/techspecs includes the current comments from Tableau - it works on Mac and Windows only.